# Laravel Redis driver not supported error

Tags: laravel, redis, phpredis

I switched branches yesterday to see that my environments file disappeared.  Once I restored the file, I started getting the following error when going to my app in my browser:

```
message: "Driver [“rediscache”] not supported.", type: "InvalidArgumentException", key: undefined
```

Any idea on what's going on or how to resolve this?  I'm a novice developer so I'm pretty far out of my depth here.  I have no idea what's going on or how to proceed.  I went through the phpredis setup procedure again and everything seems to be set up correctly.  I destroyed and recreated my VM and ran composer update and I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was just that for some reason I had the stylized double quote characters surrounding my cache driver value in my environments file.

Changing:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=“rediscache”
```

to:

```
CACHE_DRIVER="rediscache"
```

fixed the whole problem.

Ugh.  Lesson learned.  Copy and paste at my own risk.